# What is there a factor of 3 in Pearson's 2nd skewness (median skewness)

Tags: r, statistics, mean, median, standard-deviation

I've been searching for this and I cannot seem to find an easy answer.  Can someone please explain why there is a factor of three is Pearson's second skewness coefficient (median skewness).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness

It is defined as:

```
3*(mean-median)/std_dev
```

The

```
(mean-median)/std_dev
```

makes sense, as it is a measure of how much the median is away from the mean compared to the standard deviation, but Pearson's coefficient adds a factor of 3.  I'd like to know why this is, and why or why not this is a better measure than simply:

```
(mean-median)/std_dev
```

Comment: Please ask this question on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can find an explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_skew#History). Don't know if it's true though.